# jQuery how to find hyperlink by href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to find hyperlink by href attribute i tried  but no success with it not sure what am doing wrong

here is the html

```js
jQuery('a[href*="15628"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';console.log('no ajax');return false;");
jQuery('a[href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';console.log('no ajax');return false;");

jQuery('ul#menu-main_menu').find('a[href*="15628"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';console.log('no ajax');return false;");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main_menu drop_down right">
  <ul id="menu-main_menu" class="">
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home page_item page-item-15260 current_page_item narrow">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="">
        <i class="menu_icon blank fa" />
        <span>Home</span>
        <span class="plus" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15685" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow active">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628" class="current">
        <i class="menu_icon blank fa" />
        <span>FAQs</span>
        <span class="plus" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628" class="current">
  <i class="menu_icon blank fa" />
  <span>FAQs</span>
  <span class="plus" />
</a>
```

Comment: You are selecting it correctly, but aren't binding the click event properly. Change `.prop(` to `.on(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways, but your binding of the event is incorrect.  See these examples from your code and one I added.

```js
console.log(jQuery('a[href*="15628"]').length);
console.log(jQuery('a[href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628"]').length);
jQuery('a[href="https://stackoverflow.com/"]').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('home link');
  //  window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';

  return false;
});
jQuery('a[href*="15628"]').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('no ajax1', $(this).attr('href'));
  //  window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';

  return false;
});
jQuery('a[href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628"]').on("click", function(event) {
  console.log('no ajax0', $(this).attr('href'));
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  //  window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';
  return false;
});

jQuery('ul#menu-main_menu').find('a[href*="15628"]').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('no ajax2', $(this).attr('href'));

  //  window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';

  return false;
});
jQuery('ul#menu-main_menu').on("click", 'a[href*="15628"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('no ajax3', $(this).attr('href'));

  //  window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628';

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main_menu drop_down right">
  <ul id="menu-main_menu" class="">
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home page_item page-item-15260 current_page_item narrow">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="">
        <i class="menu_icon blank fa">
    </i><span>Home</span><span class="plus">
    </span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15685" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow active">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628" class="current">
        <i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/?page_id=15628" class="current"><i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
```

Comment: thanks ya i got the point i should have used click()  it worked now . thanks for putting so much example it will help someone for sure :)

Answer (score 3):

You've misidentified the problem.

`jQuery('a[href*="15628"]')`  is finding the element just fine (I haven't checked the others).

However, the value you assign to the `onclick` property must be a **function** and you are assigning a string.

You should use [the `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to assign event handlers when you are using jQuery though.